# If I find myself defining a Component class and a ComponentInstance class, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, generics, generic-programming

I am trying to write a program for designing electrical circuits in C++. At run-time, the user will be able to create a new type of component and will define its various attributes (e.g. number of pins, names of pins). They will then be able to create a circuit which includes multiple instances of these various user-created component types. When I tried to code this, I initially created a `Component` class, which would represent a type of component and store its number of pins, pin names, etc., as well as a `ComponentInstance` class to represent an instance of this component as part of a circuit. The `ComponentIntance` class maintains a reference back to its `Component` so that any changes to the `Component` will be reflected in its instances.

When I sat down and thought about my code, this seemed a bit clumsy. I am using an object-oriented language which provides facilities for exactly this kind of relationship: classes to represent a type and objects to represent an instance. The issue that I am having is that I don't know how to take advantage of these facilities because the type relies on user-provided input. Additionally, the user should be able to change the properties of the type and have these changes reflected in existing instances.

I thought that perhaps I should use some sort of template trickery to create this system, but I don't know if this is the right method, and even if it is, I don't know how to actually implement it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not obvious what functionality ComponentInstance would have, so I would say YAGNI. Also, in C++, the properties of a class are fixed at compile-time.

Comment: @latedeveloper How would you suggest I create multiple instances of a type of component, each with its own connections to other components?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to achieve. Templates are very powerful yet demanding tool to make *programming* itself easier. It won't help you with run-time thingies much though...

Comment: Component c1( ... ), c2( ...) , c3( ... ) where the ellipsis represent different constructor parameters.

Comment: @latedeveloper But all of those components share some data, like number of pins. I want the user to be able to update the number of pins that a component has and have it instantly reflected in all of its instances. How would you implement this?

Comment: I would probably have PinLayout class (not derived from Component).

Comment: @latedeveloper OK, well there are a number of other properties of components that should be shared that I left out of my original question for simplicity. When it is created, it has a number of possible schematic representations and circuit board representations and such. Also, I feel that I should add that, as of now, my Component and ComponentInstance classes are not derived from each other at all.

Comment: So, create classes for them too.

Comment: @latedeveloper I fail to see the difference between your suggestion and my initial implementation. I have essentially already done what you are saying, but all of the properties of a component type were grouped into a single class instead of spread out.

Comment: One of the major problems that beginners in OO have is that they don't create enough classes, leading to the so-called "god class" syndrome.

Comment: @latedeveloper I understand what you are saying and will try to move the individual parts of a component type into their own classes. Will it make a difference if, instead of having my component instances share references to these individual parts, they share a reference to a Component class which acts as a facade?

Comment: Search the internet for the "C++ Factory Design Pattern".  A factory uses a common base class then returns instances of child classes based on a criteria.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews From what I understand, factories are typically used when you want to create one instance of a subclass of an abstract base without necessarily knowing which subclass it is. I don't see how this pattern could be applied to my situation.

Comment: You have a base class, `Component`, and many subclasses of `Component`.  You may want to create components based upon keywords in an initialization file or text file (I believe it's called a netlist).  Review and see if it can help.  Also, this may help you decide on the methods and members of the Component base class; so that you can have a database (container) of `Component` and iterate through it generically (such as routing or placement).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am confused. Right now I don't have any subclass in relating Component and ComponentInstance. They are two separate classes. I cannot subclass Component for every type of component, because they are created by the user at runtime.

Comment: What's the difference between `Component` and `ComponentInstance`.  In common OOP parlance, an *instance* is a variable of a given type.  In electronics, a *resister* is a type of component, a *capacitor* is a type of component, so is an *integrated circuit*.  A component may have a "bounding box" describing the area or footprint it occupies on the PCB, so the bounding box would be a member of Component.  So, again, why do you need `ComponentInstance`?

Comment: If you want the User to enter a component and attributes of the component, sounds like the purpose of a Factory pattern.

Comment: I want the user to be able to create a type of component, which would be an instance of class Component. This would contain the attributes of a type of component (e.g. Number of pins, pin names) which are independent of how it is connected to other components. I also want the user to be able to create a circuit, which is built up of instances of a class ComponentInstance, which contains a reference back to the Component object which represents its type.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews perhaps we are somehow referring to different Factory patterns? I know of two. One is used to choose between one of several sets of subclasses by subclass in an AbstractFactory. The other let's subclasses of an abstract base choose what type of object they would like to instantiate. Which do you mean? And how would you apply it? Because I fail to see any application here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132131/discussion-between-theo-sandstrom-and-thomas-matthews).

Answer (score 1):

From what you said below:

> Additionally, the user should be able to change the properties of the type and have these changes reflected in existing instances.

It seem the user can change the properties *at run time*. If so, then template parameters won't be useful for these properties, since they must be determined and fixed at compile time.

I have seen similar problems when working on a specialized EDA library. Because the EDA library needs to do design exploration at run time, the properties of circuit elements cannot be fixed at compile time of the library. We ended up creating one class for each basic type of elements: one for registers, one for muxes, one for buffers, one for buses and signals, etc. Each class contains the following data members:

- A basic type identifier as `static const std::string typeName;`
- An element identifier as `const std::string elementName;`
- Member objects for inputs, outputs, clocks, memories, etc., as `std::vector`'s and/or `std::map`'s

Two instances of the same class should always have different `elementName`'s. They have the same circuit properties if and only if they have the same member object sizes.

In our case, the user couldn't/wouldn't change properties of all elements of some property to a different property (such as changing all 32-bit registers to 64-bit wide). If this is what you want, perhaps a mapping from the property setting to the set of circuit elements with that setting could be used:

```
std::map<std::pair<"register", 32>,
         std::set<Register> > register32_elements;
```

If there are *N* `Register` elements of 32 bits, the complexity to change all of them to 64 bits will be O(*N*). But we'd need to update each individual register anyway. This may be an alternative that creates fewer number of C++ classes (and probably lines of code) than your approach.

Hope this helps...

Comment: That makes sense for an application with limited numbers of components (registers, multiplexers, buffers, etc.) because you can just make a class for each one. How does it work when the user is able to define as many different component as they want?